# BS4 get the TH data within the table

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to read data from a website which has a table like this:

```
<table border="0" width = "100%">
    <tr>
        <th width="33%">Product</th>
        <th width="34%">ID</th>
        <th width="33%">Serial</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align='center'>
            <a target="_TOP" href="Link1.html">ProductName</a>
            <br>
            <a href='Link2.html' TARGET='_TOP'><img src='https://?uid=1'></a>
        </td>

        <td align='center'>
            <a target="_TOP" href="Link2.html">ProductID</a>
            <br>
            <a href='Link2.html' TARGET='_TOP'><img src='https://?uid=2'></a>
        </td>

        <td align='center'>
            <a target="_TOP" href="Link3.html">ProductSerial</a>
            <br>
            <a href='Link2.html' TARGET='_TOP'><img src='https://?uid=3'></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and all I want from this table is the ProductID which is content inside of the  tag.

The problem is, I am trying to use BS4 for this, to find the TAG, and read inside of it, but how to accurately point BS4 to it?

I have tried:

```
with open("src/file.html", 'r') as inf:
        html = inf.read()
        soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, features="html.parser")
    for container in soup.find_all("table", {"td": ""}):
        print(container)
```

But doesn't work..Is there Any way to achieve this? To read the content inside of the a tag?

Comment: The expected output isn't clear. What exactly do you want to scrape?

Comment: <a target="_TOP" href="Link2.html">ProductID</a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`:nth-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type) CSS selector:

```
print(soup.select_one("td:nth-of-type(2) a:nth-of-type(1)").text)
```

Output:

```
ProductID
```